# R: how to make the same scale for dots across multiple dotplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to plot dotplots with the same scale in terms of dots, but I was not successful.

Here is my first dotplot:
[image]

Here is my second dotplot:
[image]

I want both dotplots to have a scale for "Odds.Ratio" from 10 to 250 (10, 50, 100, 150, 200 and 250).

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Condition, y = Term, 
                        color = Adjusted.P.value, size = Odds.Ratio,
                        method = 'histodot', binpositions = 'all', binwidth = 0.75)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = 0, face = "plain")) + 
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("")
```

Here is my input data [Reactome_up](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11g7rPfIrSHEfY-GORufMQFDQ5AO2kwXP/view?usp=sharing), [Reactome_down](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LIM7AxJeTweNU-XaNrKvsS0LuAF3hgqY/view?usp=sharing):

```
data <- read.delim("Reactome_down.txt")
head(data)
```

Thank you for your help!
Olha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `scale_size`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Condition, y = Term, 
                        color = Adjusted.P.value, size = Odds.Ratio,
                        method = 'histodot', binpositions = 'all', binwidth = 0.75)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = 0, face = "plain")) + 
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("") + scale_size(limits = c(0,250))
```